# JQuery droppable lost on clone

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on an application that requires me to clone a JQuery object that is droppable.

A quick demo with unnecessary code stripped out is:

```
var $droppable = $("#droppable");
$droppable.droppable({
    accept : "#draggable",
    hoverClass : "thickBorder",
    drop : function () {
        alert("thanks");
    }
});

var $cloned = $droppable.clone(true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tGg9Y/

---

I have used .clone(true), and other event handlers like click continue to work, but the droppable is lost.

I even tried to directly reset the droppable using:

```
$cloned.droppable($droppable.droppable('option'));
```

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't perform a deep copy of the `element`, and you reapply the droppable plugin on it, it should work.

```
var $cloned = $droppable.clone(false);
```

I think it is not very safe to copy an element that has a plugin applied to it, unless you are 100% sure that the way the plugin was designed and coded could support multiple DOM elements using the same plugin instance.

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yYwya/1/) that demonstrate one reason it could be an issue, but there could be many others.

HTML

```
<div id="initial">Initial</div>
```

JS

```
function SomePlugin(el) {
    var $el = this.$el = $(el);

    $el.mouseenter(function () {
            //works for this handler because we did not use a closure variable
            $(this).css({ backgroundColor: 'red'});
        })
        .mouseleave(function () {
            //won't work for this one because because we are referencing $el
            //wich will always point to the other element
            $el.css({ backgroundColor: 'white'});
        });
}

//instanciate plugin
var $initial = $('#initial'), $clone;
new SomePlugin($initial);

$clone = $initial.clone(true).html('clone').attr('id', 'clone').appendTo(document.body);
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation of what my problem was.  I actually needed to keep other even handlers in my use case, so I had to keep .clone(true), but it worked if I destroyed the droppable before cloning and then reapplied the droppable to both.

Of course, in my event handlers I couldn't use any closure-level variables (as your jsFiddle demonstrated)

Answer (score 0):

just change your code to this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/tGg9Y/3/)

```
     var $cloned = $droppable.clone(false);
```